# Making a permutation function that outputs all possible permutations of array?

Tags: c++

I've seen some examples of of how to do this, such as this one:

```
void permutation(char * arr, int curr, int size)
{
  if(curr == size-1)
  {
    for(int a=0; a<size; a++)
        cout << arr[a] << "\t";
    cout << endl;
}

  else
  {
    for(int i=curr; i<size; i++)
    {
        swap(&arr[curr], &arr[i]);
        permutation(arr, curr+1, size);
        swap(&arr[curr], &arr[i]);
    }
  }
```

}

However, i'm trying to make a function that only takes in the array, the size, and an ostream output for the permutation function....for example:

void Permutations(int* items, const int& size, ostream& out)

I can't wrap my head around how to do it with just the size, how exactly would one go about doing this?

Comment: what do you mean "just the size"?

Comment: Is there a special reason that you want to get rid of the `curr` as the function argument?

Comment: `std::next_permutation` is a good starting point.

Comment: you do it like this: `void Permutations(char * arr, int size) { return permutation(arr, 0, size) }`. Here, the function `Permutations` takes just the array and its size. You can add an `ostream` argument if you want.

Comment: It makes since when you can modify the size variable, but what about when the size is declared const?

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind this is to swap every character, with the last one, and then call permutation again on the same string, but with size smaller by 1. Because we're using the size parameter to keep track of the size of the substrings we're working on, arr HAS to be null terminated. You could easily change the function to have an extra ostream parameter if you want.

The size value is changed at the start instead of being changed on a new call to allow for the elegant sizeof( str ) syntax.

[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b09eaae9a18ef766)

```
#include <iostream>

void swap( char* f, char* t ){
    char temp = *f;
    *f = *t;
    *t = temp;
}

void permutation(char arr[], int size)
{
    --size;

    if( size == 0 ){ 
        std::cout << arr << std::endl;
        return; 
    }

    for(int i=0; i < size; i++)
    {
        swap(&arr[size - 1], &arr[i]);
        permutation(arr, size);
        swap(&arr[size - 1], &arr[i]);
    }
}

int main(){
    char str[] = "0123";

    permutation( str, sizeof(str) );
}
```

Comment: It makes since when you can modify the size variable, but what about when the size is declared const?